# removing wildcard imports in pom

Tags: java, regex, static, pom.xml

I have a spotless plugin to validate check-style.

I want to disallow wildcard imports, so I added this code block inside the plugin:

```
<replaceRegex>
    <name>Remove wildcard imports</name>
    <searchRegex>import\s+[^\*\s]+\*;(\r\n|\r|\n)</searchRegex>
    <replacement>$1</replacement> </replaceRegex>
```

But the thing is this code is working for only imports that start with import. It does not catch static imports.
For example:
import com... (code catches this)
import static com.. (does not catch this)

How do I refactor this regex? Could you please help me ? Thanks.

Comment: Start with `import(\s+static)?\s+` instead?

Comment: I tried it but, getting this error ->  com.diffplug.spotless:spotless-maven-plugin:2.27.2:check failed: com.palantir.javaformat.java.FormatterException

Comment: Or like `<searchRegex>import\s+(?:static\s+)?[^*\s]+\*;(\r\n|\r|\n)</searchRegex>`